# Accessing data stored in HttpContext.Current.Items across threads

Tags: c#, caching, model-view-controller, httpcontext

I am currently working on a system that makes calls to an external service and caches some of the data in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection for performance. The data can change quite regularly and it is user sensitive which is why we are currently storing it only for the duration of the current HttpRequest.

Example:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Items[cacheKey] != null)
{
    LogHelper.Debug<ExampleService>("[- CACHED RESULT -] GetUser({0})", () => email);
    return (ExampleUser)HttpContext.Current.Items[cacheKey];
}

using (var client = new UserServiceClient())
{
    using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        LogHelper.Debug<ExampleService>("GetUser({0})", () => email);
        exampleUser = svc.GetUser(email);
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(cacheKey, exampleUser);
    }
}
```

In my local environment this behaves as expected and mostly also does in staging where the same thread is used for the duration of the request however in production this is not the case and there are still multiple calls to the external service in the same request. This can be seen from the logs which show that the value in `HttpContext.Current.Items[cacheKey]` is not returned in cases where the Thread ID does not match the original request.

This I guess means that my current understanding of `HttpContext.Current.Items` is wrong and that this is not a suitable solution for my needs.

My question therefore is can this be made to work across threads in the same request and if so should it, otherwise what suitable alternative is there?

Comment: HttpContext.Current is per-thread as you already found out yourself. If you want to use HttpContext.Current of current request in some other thread - first obtain reference to it in current thread, then pass it to that another thread.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session is an area dedicated to a single user; any object stored in Session will be available only for the user/session that created it.

Comment: I understand that using session storage is not a great idea because of memory usage (this is one of many items that might be stored) but also that its not scalable for instance if the site later moves into a load balanced environment?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Session to store your data. Unfortunately it's not applicable for API-specific requests (e.g mobile device makes a call to server API). Besides, server session state requires all of your data serializable (DB session state doesn't).

If session does not satisfy your requirements, then you should go to next option: Using cache protected by something that represents your requests coming from the same user (a.k.a access token).